# Cannot run my APK in archos5IT

Tags: android

I would like to know how to run a HelloWorld application directly on my [Archos5IT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archos_Generation_5) and not on the emulator. It doesn't work at all !!! I developed an application and I would like to try it on my Archos, but doesn't work, so I went down to the HelloWorld but nothing works...

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed explanation than "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the latest firmware and go to "usb connection" to choose [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Desktop_Bus) protocol. After that reboot your Archos to be sure.. and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to get an app from Eclipse to run on my Archos 5 Internet Tablet. I'm running Windows 7, and when trying to install the device driver as given in the instructions here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#VistaUprade

there is no "ADB Interface".  I see "Archos 5S" under "Portable Devices", but when I try to update the driver software for the device by pointing to the SDK's usb driver, I get the message:

"The best driver software for your device is already installed. Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date."

Also, enabling the USB debugging option doesn't appear to be the same as it is on regular phones.  Under Settings --> Applications, there's no "Application development" option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion attribute in your AndroidMnifest.xml
Maybe your android tablet OS is lower than your minSDKVersion